# jquery set caret focus immediately after inserted text

Tags: jquery, focus, caret

I have a textarea and some smilie buttons. When a user places the cursor somewhere in the middle of the textarea and clicks a smilie button, the smilie bbcode :) is inserted as I want. The problem is the last line of code $('#message').focus(); places the cursor at the end of the textarea. How can I make the cursor go directly after the inserted smilie bbcode?

```
function smilieClick() 
{
    var $txt = jQuery('#message');
    var caretPos = $txt[0].selectionStart;
    var textAreaTxt = $txt.val();
    var txtToAdd = ':) ';
    $txt.val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos));
    $('#message').focus();
}
```

Comment: Hello. I gave you the answer. If my answer helped you, then mark it as solved by checking the box to the left of my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understood your problem correctly. The caret will be installed at the end of the added emoji.

At the end of the logic, add the line `$txt.prop('selectionEnd', caretPos + 2)`.

If I misunderstood your question, then let me know about it.

Note: Add some emoticons, and after that, move the cursor to the middle, and try adding an emoticon again.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
var $txt = jQuery("#message");
    var caretPos = $txt[0].selectionStart;
    var textAreaTxt = $txt.val();
    var txtToAdd = ":)";
    $txt.val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos));
    $txt.focus();
    $txt.prop('selectionEnd', caretPos + 2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="message"></textarea>
<button>:)</button>
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you, Sergey.

Comment: Always glad to help!